# SVG not loading into Live Server with Visual Studio Code

Tags: html, css, image, svg, path

I am new to the front-end designing world and for my webpage I want to import an SVG file to display my company logo. I used Figma in order to export my design as an SVG file, however it doesn't appear to be showing up on my live server.

I used Codepen to display my SVG, and Codepen does display my SVG. But whenever I start up the Live Server, all I see is my alternative logo text and a logo pictogram. I tried renaming my SVG file to make sure the `src` location is right, but nothing seems to work.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@600;626&display=swap');



body {
    display:block;
    margin:8px;
}

li, a {
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:600px;
    color:black;
}

header {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:space-between;
    align-items:center;
    padding:10px 10%;
}


.Nav_links {
    list-style: none;
}

.Nav_links li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px 20px;
}

.Nav_links li, a:hover {
    transition: 400ms;
    color:grey;
}

#Login_nav {
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    gap:1rem;
}

.switchIconRotate {
    transform-origin: center;
    transition: 0.2s;
  }

  .fa-angle-down {
      color:#6161F2
  }

.iconUp .fa-solid {
    transform-origin: center;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  
#Demobutton {
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color: #4EC843;
    border-radius:34px;
    border:none;
    color: white;
    width:130px;
    height:35px;
    font-family:"Open Sans", sans-serif;
    font-weight:600px;
    font-size:14px;
}

#Demobutton:hover {
    background-color: #20D62C;
    transition:800ms;
  }

#Navbarline {
    width:80%;
    border-width:1.5px;
    opacity:15%;
}
```

```html
    <body> 
        <header>
            <img class="logo" src="/logo.svg" alt="logo">
            <nav> 
                <ul class="Nav_links">
                    <li><a class="switch" href="#">Features <i class="fa-solid fa-angle-down switchIconRotate"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>  
            </nav>
            <div id="Login_nav">
        <a href="#">Login</a> 
        <a href="#"><button id="Demobutton">Get demo</button></a> 
            </div>
        </header>
        <hr id="Navbarline"></hr>




        <script src="/script.js"></script>
    </body>
```

Comment: Is the path to the svg correct?

Comment: Try to verify if the svg is present in that path

Comment: by path do you mean the folder location? Because my svg is inside user files>images>logo.svg. @HamzaRadouan

Comment: Change your file path to `src="/images/logo.svg"` and see if that works.

Comment: No that doesn't work also

Comment: Couple of years ago Live Server had a bug when SVG was used. Try Five Server

Comment: I downloaded five server and the problem is still apparent

Comment: I copied the svg markup into my vscode and now it does appear, but isn't it a little bit unconventional to do it that way?